# Is there an ActionScript 3 alternative php's stripos?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to search a string from a specific point onward.

I'm looking for a r ether low case or upper case then finding the dash after the r's location. I can do this in php but in ActionScript 3 string.search always starts at the beginning of the string. Is there an alternative that works more like stripos in ActionScript 3?

Comment: Static? Alternative? It's the sort of stuff my phone does with my texts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf%28%29) optionally takes the offset within the "haystack" as an argument, and except for the case-insensitive nature of stripos it will do what stripos does.  You can make indexOf case-insensitive by using [toLowerCase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) on both the "needle" and the "haystack".  Using the variable names as found in the [stripos documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) that should give something like:

```
var position:int = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase(),offset);
```